# Python Turtle detect mouse release event on screen, not a turtle

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

How do you detect a mouse release event on a turtle screen? There is only `onscreenclick` but no corresponding release event. Is there something I can do using the tkintercanvas backend?

Comment: You could apply a listener thread directly on the mouse bypassing the turtle API.  see https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html

Comment: `turtle` uses `tkinter` and you may try to access `tkinter.Canvas` and use `canvas.bind("<Release>", function_name)`

Answer (score 4):

`turtle` uses `tkinter` and you may access `tkinter.Canvas` and bind your function to event `<ButtonRelease>` for all buttons, or  `<ButtonRelease-1>` for left button, `<ButtonRelease-3>` for right button, `<ButtonRelease-2>` for middle button.

```
def on_button_released(event):
    print('event :', event)
    print('button:', event.num)
    print('x, y  :', event.x, event.y)

canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease>", on_button_released)  # <-- function's name without `()`
```

Full working code

```
import turtle

#def any_button(event):
#    print('[any_button] event :', event)
#    print('[any_button] button:', event.num)
#    print('[any_button] x, y  :', event.x, event.y)

def left_button(event):
    print('[left_button] event:', event)

def right_button(event):
    print('[right_button] event:', event)

def middle_button(event):
    print('[middle_button] event:', event)
    
canvas = turtle.getcanvas()

#canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease>', any_button)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', left_button)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-2>', middle_button)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>', right_button)

turtle.mainloop()
```

---

Few other interesting events:

- `<Button>` - button press
- `<ButtonPress>` - button press
- `<Motion>` - mouse move
- `<Control-Button>` - button with key `Ctrl`
- `<Shift-Button>` - button with key `Shift`

Answer (score 2):

My inclination would be to create the missing turtle screen method in the style of other turtle event methods so that you can specify the button, stack events if desired, and remove the event when no longer needed.  Something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def onrelease(self, fun, btn=1, add=None):
    if fun is None:
        self.cv.unbind("<ButtonRelease-%s>" % btn)
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            x, y = self.cv.canvasx(event.x)/self.xscale, -self.cv.canvasy(event.y)/self.yscale
            fun(x, y)

        self.cv.bind("<ButtonRelease-%s>" % btn, eventfun, add)

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(lambda x, y: print("screen click"))
onrelease(screen, lambda x, y: print("screen release"))

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')  # make it easier to click!
turtle.onclick(lambda x, y: print("turtle click"))
turtle.onrelease(lambda x, y: print("turtle release"))

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: very good idea :) you could send it to turtle's author(s)